# How is the attacked fleet selected?

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

When there's more than one hostile fleet of the same faction at a system, and one of my fleets chooses the attack option in that system, the game always picks the attacked fleet for me. How is the attacked fleet determined? Is there anything I can do to affect this?

Comment: It's been a while since I played this game, but I think I remember it being the fleet with the most MP.

Comment: @DCShannon so far that's my impression as well. Can you add this as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have more than 500 hours of playtime on Endless Space.

I haven't played the game in a while, so haven't explicitly tested this, but I recall that the fleet with the highest MP is selected.

As some kind of evidence, note that you have to destroy *all* fleets with *any* MP before being allowed to attack the AI's invasion fleets, even it's just one scout ship.